# What makes a man wise?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

I asked my grandfather: "What makes a man *wise*?"

He typed out this:

```
GGRBBBBR
```

Confused, I asked him to explain....

He ignored me and typed out the following:

```
-−−− -−−- −−- −−-- ---−
```

> Please, I really want to know what makes a man wise!

---

#### HINTS!

Hint 1:

> You must solve the second line first.

Hint 2:

> The "Dark Lines" are just noise.

Hint 3:

> Fried eggs.

Hint 4:

> Somebody got *really* close already (in the comments of Chowzen's answer)

- Hint 3 is directly related to Hint 4 (3 will help solve 4)
- Hint 3 was a response towards a specific comment(s) on one of the answers.

Hint 5:

> The Morse code in the box is treated the same as the colors. Here's a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N39CF.png) to a cleaned up image.

Comment: [Early to bed, early to rise, makes a man helzy, WELZy, and wise.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/early-to-bed-and-early-to-rise-makes-a-man-healthy-wealthy-and-wise)

Comment: Not what I'm looking for, but very cute. :D

Comment: @WELZ Re hints, see [this nice guidance on when to add hints](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5020/5373), [this general hint advice thread](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5005/5373), and [this post about what to do if nobody's getting it](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2799/5373).

Comment: Hint 4 was added 20 minutes before this comment.

Comment: @WELZ (Comment for the future: The final two transformations needed to arrive at the answer are, insofar as I can tell, entirely unclued. Yes, that makes for a hard puzzle. But "What have I got in my pocket?" is a hard riddle, for much the same reason — there's nothing there to guide a solver to the solution, making it fairly literally a case of "guess what I was thinking here" ... which is the hallmark of an unfair, and often unfit, puzzle. You don't have to make steps explicit, but they should at least be clued in some way...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is

> White Hair

This is answer is arrived at, by

> Taking the sequence created by combining the morse code with the RGB color values of the colored circles in the link from Chowzen's post, in the order GGRBBBBR. The resultant sequence is [21, 22, 22, 10, 14, 18, 05, 07, 21] which, with an a1z26, gives us ["u", "v", "v", "j", "n", "r", "e", "g", "u"]. Rot13 this, to get hiiwaerth, which is an anagram of, white hair

Thank you, Chowzen, for the partial answer. And NetJohn, for the rot13.

Comment: Wow, great job finding the answer, that was a tough puzzle :D

Comment: It really was a group effort

Answer (score 10):

Then, there's this thing:

> [image]
> Gotten by rot13 -ing @QuantumTwinkie 's discovery and stack.imgur-ing it. The obvi morse comes to "21", but the colors are confusing me. Which is oddly comforting...
> Then, I searched for "GGRBBBBR" and  google for it which is a pastebin page: https://pastebin.com/2Fyj0bSz I found this: .... ..--- -.-. .--- -.-, which led to this: H2CJK in morse, which leads to U2PWX after rot13, which... which... which does nothing.

Comment: Should we sort the colors by order? GGRBBBBR (2x green, red, blue, brown, black,...)

Comment: That edit made me laugh, a lot.

Comment: what was the original url to the stack.imgur?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by your first paragraph? I can't reproduce the steps to lead to that image :/

Comment: @votbear Sending "jpgzv" through rot13 gives "wctmi," and *now,* plugging it into the format https://i.stack.imgur.com/?????.png doesn't work, but that's what I did before to get that image.

Comment: Just jpgzv... is enough, no rot13.

Comment: I must've done both... HA!

Comment: Could the `GGRBBBBR` represent the R, G, or B values of the colored circles? 8 letters, 8 colors.

Comment: @NetJohn yes, it could, and I think it does, but, what to do, *what to do?*

Comment: From left to right, the html color codes are as follows. First, the bright Stripes: ff16b5, ff16b5, 0ad730, fa190e, 094112, a81905, 171a07, 1545b5. Now the dark stripes: b30f7f, b30f7f, 079722, af120a, 062e0d, 761204, 101205, 0f307f

Comment: The GGRBBBBR values ( picking out the corresponding R or G or B value) of the color codes in my last post are, for the light stripes: 22, 22, 10, 14, 18, 05, 07, 69. Now for the dark stripes: 15, 15, 07, 10, 13, 04, 05, 48. The last color is the only one with a color value above 26, so maybe an a1z26 transform could help us. Also, the morse code in the box before gives us 21. Maybe it's a cipher key?

Comment: @CalebDevine: I think your last number are wrong. You took the G code and not the R code, which would be 15 for dark and 21 for light.

Comment: @gnovice. Thank you very much. In that case, I'm confident we transform this into the the letters of the alphabet. We've got to now wonder, though, what's next

Comment: [22, 22, 10, 14, 18, 05, 07, 21] -> ["w", "w", "k", "o", "s", "f", "h", "v"]
and
[15, 15, 07, 10, 13, 04, 05, 15] -> ["p", "p", "h", "k", "n", "e", "f", "p"]

Comment: @mowwalker you may want to recalculate those...

Comment: @mowwwalker I think you used 0-index rather than 1-index. [22, 22, 10, 14, 18, 05, 07, 21] -> ["v", "v", "j", "n", "r", "e", "g", "u"] and [15, 15, 07, 10, 13, 04, 05, 15] -> ["o", "o", "g", "j", "m", "d", "e", "o"]. ROT13 is iiwaerth and bbtwzqrb?

Comment: @everyone in this comment thread, regarding the darker lines, I've added a hint.

Comment: Oops, 0-indexing just feels natural

Comment: @CalebDevine I get three colors from each of the circles and chose {ff1eb3, ff1eb3, 00d73d, f82e27, 0e431b, a5261a, 1d2010, 2f40b1} which yields {30,30,0,39,27,26,16,47}

Comment: The pastebin's got to be linked, the dates are matching (3rd of April)
The morse code over there is 5 characters, maybe an imgur link?
what if the 21 is the key to decipher this?

Comment: The pastebin page has nothing to do, maybe someone was trying to play around or something.

Comment: It's difficult to figure out the exact hex colors in the image. Can you post a version without the line noise?

Comment: @Chowzen you should update your answer with the information mentioned in the first few comments.

Comment: Ok what I've found by actually downloading the image and using digital color meter on my mac is this. In order for the RGB values in GGRBBBBR to correlate straight with values under 26 straight across, you have to either look at the darker stripes for the first four, and the lighter stripes for the second 4, or the darker stripes all the way across. That could be what the "2 1" refers to (stripes 2 for the first four, stripes 1 for the next four). I know @Welz says they're just noise but that's what I'm getting. With the first formula I get 26, 26, 24, 22, 21, 18, 8, 26. That's ZZXVURHZ.

Comment: Using just the darker stripes I get 

26, 26, 24, 22, 15, 11, 6, 18. That’s ZZXVOKFR.

Comment: I don't know, @LilyPotter. I get the values Caleb has found. I think it's clear that we are working with VVJNREGU here, we just need to find out what the 21 (or 2, 1) means and perhaps how Morse is involved.

Comment: The darker stripes are really, *irrelevant* and have nothing to do.

Comment: Ah, ok. Alright, so shifting the morse of the letters in VVJNREGU 21 cycles to the right, we get: V = B, J = Y, N = A, R = R, E = E, G = G, U = U. BBYAREGU. Some anagrams: https://new.wordsmith.org/anagram/anagram.cgi?anagram=BBYAREGU&t=500&a=n. 

Anagrams of the Rot-13 (OOLNERTH): https://new.wordsmith.org/anagram/anagram.cgi?anagram=OOLNERTH&t=500&a=n

Answer (score 9):

If you use Morse code on the slashes you get

> jpgzv

If you use GGRBBBBR

> Using the 2nd letter of green, 1st of red, 4th of blue and 1st of red you get **rrer** which might mean something.

The first hint,

> Rot13 will give you "Lbh zhfg fbyir gur frpbaq yvar svefg", to "You must solve the second line first."

Comment: I suspect you may be on the right track, given that the only characters in the first code block are "R", "G" and "B", considering the first three characters that you decoded as a well known file extension. Although, it's possible this is a coincidence.

Comment: With RGB i naturally think on colours....